# Modify each commit in current branch by bash command

Tags: bash, git, shell

- have branch with three commits
- forgot to run [Rubocop](https://rubocop.org) "linter" after I did some rebasing-amending
- CI build didn't go well
- now I want to fix the past

I could rebase the branch with edit command for each commit and do it all manually, but where is the adventure in that  Also if I'd run into a branch like that, with 20+ commits, I definitely don't want to be fixing it manually.

**What is the right way to modify existing commits by shell command?**

### Ideas / What I've tried

#### Idea 1

I know there is [*exec*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---execltcmdgt) command in rebase, but I'd probably have to include the git-add and git-commit in my command

```
 $ git rebase --exec "rubocop --autocorrect && git commit --amend" <parent branch>
...
error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
warning: execution succeeded: rubocop --autocorrect && git commit --amend
but left changes to the index and/or the working tree.
Commit or stash your changes, and then run

  git rebase --continue
```

If it is possible without it, pls let me know.

#### Idea 2

I have a script from long time ago, which I overflow-pasted together somehow. This script is reseting the author of commits. It does so via `git filter-branch --env-filter`, so *filter-branch* seems like what I am looking for.

```
 $ git filter-branch --commit-filter 'rubocop --autocorrect ' HEAD~3..HEAD
```

This command finishes, but unfortunately leaves the history untouched. Also everywhere in the man page and when I run the command, it says filter-branch is a dangerous command and nobody should be using it :/

Comment: So your goal is to (1) revisit `HEAD~3`, (2) run your linter, (3) apply some changes, then (4) apply the diff of `HEAD~3..HEAD~2`, and repeat from step 2 for all the commits?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by applying the diff, but it seems to me we're saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `git rebase` is the simplest option.  Something like this should work:

```
git rebase --exec "rubocop --autocorrect; git add -u; git commit --amend --no-edit" ...
```

`git add -u` will stage all modified files.